# Typescript create a new Record from an existing one?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to map one Record type to a new one in Typescript. Here is what I have so far, but it seems like this isn't the correct way to create a Record using map.

Any tips?

```
const data: Record<string, string> = { "test": : "Test", "test2": "Test2"}
const result = Object.keys(data).map((i): Record<string, string> => [i, data[i]])
```

Edit:

Here is the input:

```
const data: Record<string, CustomType> = { "Option 1": {"id": "123"}, "Option 2": {"id": "987"}}
const data_two: Record<string, CustomType> = { "Option 1": {"id": "567"}, "Option 2": {"id": "376"}}
```

Here is my expected output:

A `Record<string, string[]` that would look something like:

```
{ "Option 1": ["123", "567"], "Option 2": ["987", "376"] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

(1) Implement the logic in JavaScript first

(2) Type the JavaScript properly for TypeScript. Declare the output object type as `{ [K in keyof typeof data]: string[] }` and you can get the structure you want.

```
type CustomType = { id: string };
const data: Record<string, CustomType> = { "Option 1": {"id": "123"}, "Option 2": {"id": "987"}}
const data_two: Record<string, CustomType> = { "Option 1": {"id": "567"}, "Option 2": {"id": "376"}}

const output: {
    [K in keyof typeof data]: string[]
} = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(data).map(key => [key, []])
);
for (const obj of [data, data_two]) {
    for (const [key, customType] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        output[key].push(customType.id)
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYBVzQLxQN5QCWAJgFxRIBOhAdgOZQC+A3AFADGyNSUxAhsD7kAShE6ViAHiq06AGliIUGLAD4ouAgCIA8mGCEuUAIxbyeLSTNQtxgEwBmLYwW79hmlDvWLV8loBOAA4AdmdGDi4efkEAfWAAd2QRMWQJaWBqegV4JDRMSHVNGz0DI1NzS2JrLQBWADYwlxL3I29KvxsHEPrw1kjuYChkOGAwUfNWKGmoAG0AaSJPAGsIEGQAMyhQSE3eAT4AXXIZelnD1kYNKB0AIwArMWAAOg3KNABRGkzCCAQACimMzuj3YL1WIABMT4AEpnqg+GB-hCNOpZhCFOdDjDWDC2Bs0lB-pxBsMHsMtrNoQpofEktj8EDpgTKESSTx0WsFOwlPksIcKTcHk9nhBvtQ-v9kA8YTDGTMFcNRuNgJyQIdnuMEAALYm8lSQZ4kHEKiKMIA)

Comment: Oh I understand that they are tuples in this example. 

I've just tried to simplify the code i'm working with. I just need to be able to take one Record, and create a new Record from it.

Comment: It looks like you may have oversimplified then, since the JavaScript logic you're implementing results in tuples, not the Records you want. Can you edit your question to include the *actual* code, including the expected output?

Comment: Okay, I've updated the question with some more details

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question. 

Not as clean as I was hoping, I'll have to explore an alternative.